# Перескакивающий div при изменении масштаба окна

Tags: css

Последний блок перескакивает при уменьшении масштабов окна

JSFIDDLE :    http://jsfiddle.net/3etetpc5/

Код :

```
<div class="wrapper">
        <div>1</div>
        <div>2</div>
        <div>3</div>
</div>

.wrapper {
    width: 104px;
    border: 2px solid black;
    background: #e6e6e6;
}

.wrapper div {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 30px;
    background: #fff;
    border: 1px solid green;
}
```

Comment: вместо `display` в `div` добавьте `float: left`, а у враппера добавьте `overflow: hidden`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/3etetpc5/2/

```css
.wrapper{
    display: inline-block;
    border: 2px solid black;
    background: #e6e6e6;
}

.wrapper div{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 30px;
    background: #fff;
    border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
        <div>1</div>
        <div>2</div>
        <div>3</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
.wrapper div {
    background: #ffffff none repeat scroll 0 0;
    border: 1px solid #008000;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 32px;            // <---------------
    box-sizing: border-box; // <---------------
}
```

Проблема возникает из за глюков рендера, причем не все браузеры страдают такой проблемой. По моему мнению - проблема разработчика браузера, чем верстальщика,хотя и с этим справиться можно, но и не всегда возможно. Нужно это учитывать и не рвать на себе волосы :)

Answer (score 0):

Может так?

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="d">1</div>
    <div class="d">2</div>
    <div class="d">3</div>
</div>

.wrapper{
    display: table;
    table-layout: auto;
    border-spacing: 1px;
    font-size: 80%;
}

.d{
    display: table-cell !important;
    display: inline; /* для IE */
    padding:4px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    width:100px;
    min-width:100px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pbk478cp/3/